# Обращение к объекту

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте :) Вопросик по JS.
Использую объекты как ассоциативные массивы. Возник вопрос: как обратиться к объекту, если прямо вызвать через имя нельзя - имя хранится в переменной. 
Например, имеется много объектов - **elem1**, **elem2**, **elem3**... Из объекта **elem1** нужно получить значение по ключу **numb**. 
`elem1.numb` - всё просто, но проблема в том, что у меня название объекта хранится в переменной (**nameobject**). Как быть? `nameobject.numb` не пройдёт - это понятно :D

Answer (score 2):

```
nameobject[numb]
```

[К чтению](http://shamansir.github.io/JavaScript-Garden/).

Comment: Это же вроде работает только с ключами, нет?

Comment: Это всего лишь способ доступа к методу или свойству объекта.  
Прочтите информацию по ссылке- уделив ей полчаса Вы больше никогда не зададитесь подобными вопросами.